# Authenticating users with tokens useless after HTTPS?

Tags: security, http, https

I am building a mobile application that include users doing various things in the app and I started off with authenticating all user actions inside the app using a token that is stored locally on the device. My biggest concern was that anyone can sniff the network and look at the http requests I make inside the app and thus send false requests on behalf of a real user. Something like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/postmessage?user=abcd&token=35sxt&msg=Hi
```

Now, I am using HTTPS though and no one can see my domain name nor the data being sent. So I'm inclined to get rid of tokens all together and do just this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/postmessage?user=abcd&msg=Hi
```

Am I correct in assuming I don't need tokens anymore? The whole purpose of them for me was making sure that no one can make an action on behalf of another user without authorization and now it seems pointless that I still use tokens. Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you were correct that having the token in the URL (or anywhere else) was a security risk over HTTP.  However, now that you are on HTTPS, it should not matter whether you have the API token in the URL or you are transmitting it in some other way.  The URL should be as secure as any other part of the transaction.  I say "should" because in practice your internal infrastructure may do logging, metrics collection or reporting that reveals the URL slightly more easily than you intend.  And the client may submit the visited URL (but not other info) to its own logging system or to a smart search service like Google, etc.  But for most use cases and in most configurations this is not a major issue.

But it sounds from your question like you are talking about not removing the token from the URL and adding it to the HTTP headers or some other fashion, but actually removing the token concept entirely.

So what you should ask is, what is special about HTTPS that makes the token unnecessary?  HTTPS secures the communication but it does not authenticate the client.  Except in very unusual configurations, anyone can connect via HTTPS and issue commands, and unless you have some method of authentication the HTTPS will not protect you from unauthorized access.  If you are using cookies for authentication, or if you are passing the token via HTTP headers (which is actually how I prefer to handle tokens when possible) then your need for authentication is satisfied and you do not need the token.  If you do not have any other form of authentication, and you need authentication for security on your website, then you do need the token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Currently, I authenticate users (with username and password) first time they launch the app, then I store a cookie with their username and token and then use userid+token in any request they make to validate it. I am just thinking that since I'm using HTTPS now that I can skip the token entirely. So authenticate the users first time and then allow them to do actions based on their usernames only. Am I making any sense?

Comment: @MinaHany no, HTTPS prevents _others_ from listening in on the communication between client and server. It does not hinder malicious clients. A user can view and alter HTTPS traffic before it's sent, so user A can do a request with user B's name.

Comment: @CodeCaster so if A found out the http request that B sends, they can do requests on their behalf after that token or no token, but other users would still be protected if I had a token because A doesn't know their tokens?

Comment: @Mina that is partially correct (if you replace 'because' with 'as long as'). A also doesn't need to know what B does, A has access to the application so can analyze all HTTP(S) requests, and only has to replace `UserA` with `UserB` in his forged requests. A token prevents this.

Comment: It sounds like you have no way to prevent people from modifying their own cookies, so I agree with @CodeCaster in that you do need the token (which is presumably a secret and different for each user) in this scheme.  You might want to look at alternative methods of handling user credentials, though.  For starters, your web app can simply check the cookie itself for the token rather than have the client insert it in the URL.  But even better, you could encrypt the cookies you leave on the clients' computers so that they cannot modify them -- this is what Django and Rails do nowadays.

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you! And thanks for the suggestion Andrew, I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is basically used to ensure that you are communicating with a webstie that you intended to and to encrypt communication data so that even if someone intercepts your data, it makes no sense to them.

For e.g. if you are placing an order on Amazon and making a payment, 
HTTPS will ensure that:

1. you are actually submitting payment details to Amazon
2. your payment data is encrypted when flowing from your browser to Amazon webserver.

When communicating over HTTPS, browsers validates servers digital certiifcate to confirm their identity , then a key is exchanged between server and browser to encrypt data flow between browser and server.

By default HTTPS does not authenticate client. So if you have some actions specific to particular user, you still needs authentication token from client.
But if the token is passed as query parameter in URL itself, then it is still exposed to attackers, so send the token in cookie over HTTPS.

It is also recommended to mark your cookies as secure, to ensure that cookies are sent only over  a secure (https) connection and not over http as it can reveal user details.

Hope it helps.